# Converting image folder to numpy array is consuming the entire RAM

Tags: python, numpy, dataset

I am trying to convert the celebA dataset(https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/celeba-dataset) images folder into a numpy array for later to be converted into a .pkl file(for using the data as simply as mnist or cifar).

I am willing to find a better way of converting since this method is absolutely consuming the whole RAM.

```py
from PIL import Image
import pickle
from glob import glob
import numpy as np

TARGET_IMAGES = "img_align_celeba/*.jpg"

def generate_dataset(glob_files):
   dataset = []
   for _, file_name in enumerate(sorted(glob(glob_files))):
       img = Image.open(file_name)
       pixels = list(img.getdata())
       dataset.append(pixels)
   return np.array(dataset)

celebAdata = generate_dataset(TARGET_IMAGES)
```

I am rather curious on how the mnist authors did this themselves but any approach that works is welcome.

Comment: You can process files one at the time and save locally.
You can then process them with Keras using batching, which implies that only some files are loaded in memory at the time.

Comment: @bugo99iot could you provide a code example?

Comment: Have a look here: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform any kind of data on the fly in Keras and load in memory one batch at the time during training.
See [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), search for 'Example of using .flow_from_directory(directory)'.